# How to create a fixed size XML file?

Tags: java, xml, file, performance-testing

I want to create an XML file with fixed size (5 MB) in java.

How to can I make this file and write to it?

Comment: *"I want to create an XML file with fixed size (5 MB)"*  IF you mean the data in the fields of the XML, ***..why***? If you mean the XML itself, that is very hard to do without a variable size CDATA section at the end to pad it. And again, ***..why***?

Comment: I want to check the time taken to parse 5MB file with sax parser.

Comment: Then neither technique described by Cris Stringfellow nor myself will have any good effect.  Not that it is a very good test in the larger sense, but I'd create an XML with a fixed number (20 million) of custom objects filled with random values.  But even processing that chunk of records would produce a quite arbitrary number in the end.

Comment: Performance is going to differ depending on descendant count, tree depth, number of attributes, type of nodes, and a good number of other factors. Measuring the time it takes to parse 5 MB of "any XML data" is meaningless. You really should at least tell the format you want for the file.

Answer (score 1):

Fill the file initially with space filling tags (enough to equal 5MB) :

```
<placeholder></placeholder>
```

As you add records to the file, remove the space filling tags and replace with records :

```
<rec><key>a</key><val>2</val></rec>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write out `<a>` followed by 4,999,993 spaces followed by `</a>`.